# Finding exponent in an modulus equation: $3^x \bmod 17 = 11$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponential-function

Can someone tell me a way to solve the following equation for $x$ so I can solve similar problems like these:

$3^x \bmod 17 = 11$

Comment: do you mean $$3^x\equiv 11 \mod 17$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I mean $3^x mod 17 = 11$ and I want to find x

Comment: A list of algorithms for computing discrete logarithms can be found at this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Algorithms) on wikipedia.